# Django, Python, and Class Variables

Tags: python, django

I'm simultaneously learning Python while picking up Django. I'm familiar with many other languages.

In the following code snippet, `x` is a class variable of class `Foo`.

```
class Foo(object):
    x = 9000
```

Given the previous declaration, the following works fine.

`print Foo.x`

The Django framework lets you create your model by defining Python classes. It makes fields out of the different class variables in your Python classes.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Why does the following code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
import os, django
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
django.setup()
from polls.models import Question, Choice
print Question.question_text
```

throw the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Question' has no attribute 'question_text'
```

As far as I'm understanding everything my `Question` class has a single static member defined: `Question.question_text`.

Comment: what are you expecting it to print? Since the question_text field is a database attribute mapped class member it isn't intended to hold values, that's where the database kicks in. So if you're hoping for a string value to be printed it will not work. If this code were to work the best you could get is the string description of the class models.CharField, probably  <module CharField>

Comment: Django models use a *metaclass* to alter what is normal class behaviour. Use `dir(Question)` and you'll see there are *different* attributes on that class now. This is custom behaviour just for Django models however.

Comment: @Freestyle076 `<module django.db.models.CharField>` was exactly what I was hoping would show up on my screen.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you mind placing your reply as the answer to my question? I want to check-mark it as the selected answer to my quesetion. It's my first time using a language as "dynamic" as Python. I didn't realize the "looks like a duck" philosophy could reach the extents of re-defining classes on the fly. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic.

No, really.

Python classes aren't set-in-stone structure, like they are in C++.  They are, themselves, just objects — instances of another type:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

print(type(Foo))  # <class 'type'>
```

You can even make a class like you'd make any other object, by calling `type`.  This:

```
class Bar(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2
```

Is really (more or less) syntactic sugar for this:

```
Bar = type('Bar', (object,), {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

`type` takes the name of your new class, a list of its superclasses, and a dict of all the attributes of the class, and spits out a new class.

But, because `type` is just a class like any other, it's possible to *subclass it* and give it different behavior.  And this is what Django has done: it's created a subclass of `type` that does something different with the dict of attributes you pass to it.

You don't see this happening directly in your own code, but if you check `type(models.Model)`, you'll find out its type is not `type`, but something specific to Django.  It probably has "meta" in the name, because it's called a *metaclass*: the class of a class.

This is a fairly common pattern for making "declarative" libraries in Python, where the attributes of a class actually define some kind of structure.  You can see the same thing in form validation (wtforms), schema validation (colander), other ORMs (sqlalchemy), and even the stdlib enum module.

Comment: Note: I'm marking this as the "most helpful" answer, but Martijn Pieters response just under my original question was actually the more concise, to-the-point response to my question.

Answer (score 7):

Django models use a [*metaclass*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) to alter what is normal class behaviour.

Use `dir(Question)` and you'll see there are *different* attributes on that class now. This is custom behaviour just for Django models however.

If you are curious you can study [the metaclass `__new__` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L64-294), but it does a *lot* of work specific to Object Relational Mapping tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Question is an object of type type. You want an instance of Question:

```
>>> q= Question(text = "Does a dog have the buddha nature?")
```

Then you should get

> > > q.text
> > >           "Does a dog have the buddha nature?"

Note that this object will not persist unless you save() it:

```
>>> q.save()
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why Django models are different, however.